# PHP PDO query on MySQL does not return as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've been working on an iOS web service using PHP, but I'm not having very much luck. I'm attempting to safely query the database and select the id of the user when the name and password match. Unfortunatly, nothing is showing up on the page. I would assume that means the query went wrong somewhere. I've attempted using static values, but to no avail. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm positive the values are correct.

P.P.S. Yes, I know, encrypt. For the simplicity, I'm not bothering.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display errors', 1);

try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='login_test'", 'test', 'development');
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo e->getMessage();
}

$data = array($_GET['name'], $_GET['password']);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?');
$STH->execute($data);

$row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

Comment: try to echo query variable , and see what is include the try to run on sql server?

Comment: In PHP, when you get no output at all when some is expected, always there is a fatal error. Always develop code with display_errors on:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script. Your problem here is that you didn't call `$DBH->prepare('SELECT....')` but instead just tried to pass the SQL string as a method.

Comment: Later, where you `echo $STH->fetch()` that is going to print `"Array"` because the fetch call returns an array. Instead you would need `$row = $STH->fetch(); echo $row['id'];`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Done everything you said, updated it above - still nothing.

Comment: PDO errors silently by default (except the constructor). Set it up to theow an exception on any problem.  Inside your `try{}` add `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Also, `var_dump($row);` If it is `(bool)false`, well then the query just didn't return a row and the values aren't really what you expect them to be.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Added the error mode, but where would I add the var_dump() method?

Comment: Where you have `print_r($row);` If it is false, `print_r()` won't show anything. Use `var_dump($row)` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Tried it, no luck. I can verify the query SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = 'testuser' AND password = 'testpass' will work, and I'm triple checked the input values are correct. Ideas?

Comment: You get no output whatsoever, nothing even from `echo '<pre>';`? If that is the case, you have a fatal error you are not seeing. Look in your error logs.  And are you _really_ sending a user and password through `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`? Does your form use `method='post'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,

```
try {
   $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='login_test'", 'test', 'development');
   $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo /*here*/ $e->getMessage(); 
}

$data = array($_GET['name'], $_GET['password']);
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ? AND password = ?');
$STH->execute($data);
$row =$STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
print '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Nothing has been printed.

Comment: i think your query just didn't return a row and the values aren't really what you expect them to be,try to set name and password manually and debug..@ZapChance

Comment: I can verify that the query SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'testuser' AND `password` = 'testpass' will work. @Always Sunny